# Getting Mutliple results from different relationships with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am sure this question has been asked but I can't find it.

I have a social graph and I want to be able to show people suggestions based on 3 different relationships in one result.

I have 3 different nodes (Skill, Interest, Title)
Each person has a relationship of SKILL_OF, INTEREST_OF, and IS_TITLED respectively.

I would like to have a single (unique if possible) results set of Matching the person, then finding people that have the same skills, interests, and job title.

I tried to start with 2 results (and then wanted to add title on after) but here is what I have.

```
MATCH (p:Person { username:'wkolcz' })-[INTEREST_OF]->(Interest)<-[i:INTEREST_OF]-(f:Person)
MATCH(p)-[SKILL_OF]->(s:Skill)<-[sk:SKILL_OF]-(sf:Person)
RETURN f.first_name,f.last_name, sf.first_name, sf.last_name, i, s
```

I tried to make the matching person the same variable but, as you experts know, that failed. I got a result set but it doesn't make sense to me how I could then display it.

I would like a single list of first_name, last_name, username from the 2 and bonus points of I could get the matches also returned (i and s) so I could display the matching results (This person also has skill(s) in X or This person also has interest in X)

Thanks and let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

This turned out to be a very interesting problem.

I provide a solution that:

- Only returns a single result row for every person.
- Displays all the interests and skills shared by that person and `wkolcz` as separate collections. (I presume that people in the DB can have multiple interests and skills.)

The solution finds all the people with shared interests and/or skills in a single `MATCH` clause.

```
MATCH (p:Person { username:'wkolcz' })-[r1:INTEREST_OF|SKILL_OF]->(n)<-[r2:INTEREST_OF|SKILL_OF]-(f)
WHERE TYPE(r1) = TYPE(r2)
WITH f, COLLECT(TYPE(r1)) AS ts, COLLECT(n.name) AS names
RETURN f.first_name, f.last_name, f.username,
  REDUCE(s = { interests: [], skills: []}, i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(ts)-1) | CASE
    WHEN ts[i] = "INTEREST_OF"
    THEN { interests: s.interests + names[i], skills: s.skills }
    ELSE { interests: s.interests, skills: s.skills + names[i]} END ) AS shared;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/1acol7) that shows these sample results:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| f.first_name | f.last_name | f.username | shared                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Fred"       | "Smith"     | "fsmith"   | {interests=[Bird Watching], skills=[]}            |
| "Oscar"      | "Grouch"    | "ogrouch"  | {interests=[Bird Watching, Politics], skills=[]}  |
| "Wilma"      | "Jones"     | "wjones"   | {interests=[Bird Watching], skills=[Woodworking]} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw that and fixed it. I tried the UNION to get the first, last, and username into the same columns. I hadto remove myself from the list using a WHERE NOT clause I didn't think I would have to use.

MATCH (p:Person { username:'wkolcz' })
MATCH (f:Person)-[:INTEREST_OF]->(i:Interest)<-[:INTEREST_OF]-(p) WHERE NOT f.username = 'wkolcz'
RETURN f.first_name as first_name,f.last_name as last_name, i.name as related
UNION
MATCH(sf:Person)-[:SKILL_OF]->(s:Skill)<-[:SKILL_OF]-(p) WHERE NOT sf.username = 'wkolcz'
RETURN sf.first_name as first_name, sf.last_name as last_name, s.name as related

Comment: Better question now is how can I return the list with only the username, first_name, last_name, interest with the username being distinct so I can eliminate duplicates? Ultimately I would love a distinct list of people to match the user up with in which I can show both sublists of both interests and skills.

Comment: Do you want to enforce that  `s` and `sf` are the same person?

Comment: Not really. It can be anyone who matches one of those relationships but shouldn't be duplicates of the same person. So a person could match interests and be added to the list but if they match skills, they should be eliminated from the list.

Comment: So, if a person shares the same interest and skill as `wkolcz`, you do not want to show him at all in your results?

Comment: No, just searching people on 3 different criteria and pull a combined list of people but eliminating duplicates. If Patrick has the same job title and skills as me, only show him in the results once.

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you very much! I can't to try it in my project.